# Maximum amount of API calls that can be made to a .Net 4.6 MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest

I currently have an Async .Net 4.6 API sat on a 4 core server with 16GB of memory running IIS and SQL Express 2016 all on Server2016.

A customers device sends a GET with data in the URL and it works fine and is fairly bullet proof. The customer has around 20 devices sending in data every 15 minutes and the payload is very small, this works great.

However, he now wants to add 3000 devices and send data every minute. The URL payload is still the same and small.

All of the devices will be validated securely so only genuine devices get through.

Obviously I am concerned about throughput and bottlenecks and would like to understand other peoples experience where a high number of requests are coming in to an API.

Are there typical limits to the amount of requests in an API and what are best practices, I have done some inconclusive research and I am interested in your experiences.

I have read [ASP.NET Core Performance Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and it is useful, but isn't real world enough for me and it is for net core.

TIA

Comment: There is a lot of factors that can influence this. There is no real way to know unless you test it. Create yourself a small app that will bombard the server with requests and keep an eye on it. That is the only "real" way you will know. 3000 devices every minute is not really that much, but like I said, your tables, indexes etc, can have a huge inpact on performance if it is not done properly.

Comment: you can use online performance testing services like [loadimpact](https://loadimpact.com/) to get performance analysis on your api problems if any.

Comment: Anyway as you mentioned and hope you covered, you needs to check on your memory part and to confirm the maximum stress your app can handle you can check it using Soap UI for checking the API or Visual Studio Webperformance test if you have UI based application.